# RegEx: Match numbers greater or equal than 1001

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match numbers greater than or equal to 1001(or '1001'). I tried the following pattern `"^(^[1-9][0-9]{3,4}$)$"`. It matches from 1000 and above.

Comment: Why not parse it into integer and do numeric comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?!^1000$)^[1-9]\d{3,}$
```

##### Short Explanation

- `(?!^1000$)` Except the number `1000`
- `^[1-9]\d{3,}$` Match 4 and more length numbers

##### JavaScript Example

```js
let regex = /(?!^1000$)^[1-9]\d{3,}$/;

console.log(regex.test("1000"));
console.log(regex.test("1001"));
console.log(regex.test("10000"));
console.log(regex.test("99995555"));
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XoaEQE/1)

Comment: Or shorter: `(?!^1000$)^\d{4,}$` https://regex101.com/r/XoaEQE/2 - The `[1-9]` in `[1-9]\d{3,}` is redundant, since you already use Digit `\d` - just set to four or more `{4,}`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, in that case, it will match `0000` as well which is wrong.

Comment: That's a valid point. It'll also match `0100` etc. I was counting from `"0"` disregarding leading 0's.

Comment: Nice and short one. Looks like you could even compact `(?!^1000$)^` to `^(?!1000$)`